# Is there a way to block access to Windows administrative shares based on IP Address?

Tags: windows, shares

On Windows 8.1 Enterprise, I would like to know if there is a way to block access to administrative shares based on IP addresses. All I could find searching on the Internet is to disable the server service but I don't know to disable the shares entirely, just restrict its access.

Comment: No, it is not possible to block access to administrative shares based on adresses. It is possible to block access to the file sharing service byutilising the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a firewall on the computer. There are no built-in settings in the file shares to filter by IP.

You can use [Windows Firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/open-the-group-policy-management-console-to-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security) for example.

Comment: A firewall will however affect all shares, not only administrative shares.